# Configure Spring Data Couchbase on a cluster host address

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

My data people gave me the `http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools` url to connect to our Couchbase server and I've been told the `pools` suffix is the address to all the nodes in the cluster.

I'm using Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE with spring-data-couchbase 2.0.0.M1 against Couchbase 2.5.1 enterprise edition (build-1083)

Now, if I add the above url as is into the getBootstrapHosts list:

```
  @Override
  protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
    return Collections.singletonList(couchbaseProperties.getHost());
  }
```

I get a number format exception on the `8091/pools` value.

But when using the `http://127.0.0.1:8091` url I get an invalid password exception.

I reckon the first url is to be used, but not in the way I went for.

There is probably a method I should override in the AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration class, but looking at the source code didn't really enlighten me.

Here is the Couchbase configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.data.couchbase.repository" })
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.data.couchbase.config" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class CouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CouchbaseConfiguration.class);

  @Autowired
  private CouchbaseProperties couchbaseProperties;

  @Override
  protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
    return Collections.singletonList(couchbaseProperties.getHost());
  }

  @Override
  protected String getBucketName() {
    return couchbaseProperties.getBucketName();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getBucketPassword() {
    return couchbaseProperties.getBucketPassword();
  }

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
     return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
  }

  @Bean
  public ValidatingCouchbaseEventListener validationEventListener() {
    return new ValidatingCouchbaseEventListener(validator());
  }

}
```

Comment: pools suffix is an endpoint where the node will serve the "cluster map", which can be used to extract the list of all the nodes in the cluster. however, the 2.x SDK will manage to get that cluster map on its own. it only needs the ip or hostname of one or preferably two nodes for initial contact (bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your database administrators gave you `127.0.0.1` as the adress to connect to seem strange, but indeed could be valid if one node of the cluster is running colocated with the client code...

This url-based syntax was the one used for the `1.4.x` generation of SDK, and configuration is indeed a bit different in `2.x` (reflecting the evolution of the Couchbase SDK between 1.4.x and 2.x): you just need to provide the hostname or ip of each node to bootstrap from, in a list.

You should try with just `"127.0.0.1"`. It is possible also that you need to specify a bucket name and/or a password (ask your administrator). The defaults used by Spring Data Couchbase for each is `"default"` and `""` (empty password), but you can override the `getBucketName()` and `getBucketPassword()` methods from `AbsctractCouchbaseConfiguration` to change that.

PS: the `Spring Data Couchbase` documentation is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/)

Comment: I had read that Couchbase strongly advised to have the database colocated with the code.

Comment: What if I can't have the list of nodes ? We have too many nodes in fact. Why can't we keep the cluster addressing ?

Comment: the list I'm referring about is just the bootstrap list... this is a best practice for resiliency to bootstrap from at least two nodes: if one is down, the bootstrap process can still discover the whole of the cluster from the second node. After that, the SDK has a global vision of the cluster, you don't need to actually provide the exhaustive list of nodes.

Comment: I had read the docs of 1.4 and current but could not see what I should do with my pools name in the host. Our database has this above pools trailed URL and a bucket name and a password. Now I was hoping to use the current version of SDC.  You'd know how to configure these 3 variables with annotations?

Comment: The way to change the bootstrap node, bucket and password is what I explained, you do that by extending AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration... Literally the example from the doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#configuration-java

Comment: Extending that class is what I did in the first place. I shall update my question with more code then.

Comment: ok so with SDC 2.x you just need to replace "http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools" with "**`127.0.0.1`**" in your `couchbaseProperties`. The SDK will correctly reconstruct the url. If you still get an invalid password exception, well... it means that the bucket exists but is password protected with a different password than the one in your `couchbaseProperties`...

Comment: That's what I did, removing the trailing `pools` suffix, and getting my password denied. I shall see about the password issue then.

Comment: It was indeed a wrong bucket name and password. I now progressed to the next error :-)